# Meteor userId is always null

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app has the insecure and autopublish removed and accounts-password added.
`meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.find({});` also shows the presence of the only user credentials I used.
Invoking `Meteor.call('addTasks1',params);` throws the error, further checks show `Meteor.userId()` being `null` 
Why is that and how to fix it? Thanks

**update**
As per the suggested fix by Stephen Woods;
When I change the method addTasks1 on the server from `Meteor.userId()` to `this.userId`, It still throws the error.

```
///////////////////////////
//     both/both.js      //
///////////////////////////
Tasks1 = new Mongo.Collection('tasks1');


///////////////////////////
//   client/client.js    //
///////////////////////////
Template.login.events({
  'click #logMe': function() {
     var credentials = [$('#id').val(), $('#pin').val()];
     Meteor.call('logMeIn', credentials);
   }
 });

Template.footer.events({
  'click button': function () {
    if ( this.text === "SUBMIT" ) {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var params = {};
        params[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
        Meteor.call('addTasks1', params);
      }
    }
  }
});


///////////////////////////
//    server/server.js   //
///////////////////////////
Meteor.methods({
  logMeIn: function (credentials) {
     Accounts.createUser({username: credentials[0], password: credentials[1]});
  }
});

Meteor.publish('tasks1', function(){
  return Tasks1.find({userId: this.userId});
});

Meteor.methods({
  addTasks1: function (doc) {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      Tasks1.insert(doc);
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error("Not Authorized");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you type `Meteor.userId()` into the console client-side does it say null?

Comment: Yes it does that when I type it in the browser console.

Comment: Are you actually logging the user in?  Your Meteor Method logMeIn is only creating a user, not signing it in.

Comment: The docs [link](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_loggingin) says "or Accounts.createUser) is currently in progress." So I thought that the user is logged in when the Accounts.createUser is called. Hummm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log the user in, use `Meteor.loginWithPassword(<USERNAME>, <PASSWORD>)` on the client side to log a created user in.

Also, `addTasks1`, your Meteor method, is executing on the server.  You want to use this.userId instead of Meteor.userId() on the server.